# Is there a combinatorial way to see the link between the beta and gamma functions?

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions, binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

The [Wikipedia page on the beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) gives a simple formula for it in terms of the gamma function.  Using that and the fact that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, I can prove the following formula:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!} & = & \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(b+1)}{\Gamma(a+1+b+1)}\\
 & = & B(a+1,b+1)\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}t^{a}(1-t)^{b}dt\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}t^{a}\sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-t)^{i}dt\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}t^{a+i}dt\\
 & = & \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a+i}dt\\
 & = & \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\left[\frac{t^{a+i+1}}{a+i+1}\right]_{t=0}^{1}\\
 & = & \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\\
b! & = & \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{(a+b+1)!}{a!(a+i+1)}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
This last formula involves only natural numbers and operations familiar in combinatorics, and it feels very much as if there should be a combinatoric proof, but I've been trying for a while and can't see it. I can prove it in the case $a=0$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{(b+1)!}{0!(i+1)}\\
 & = & \sum_{i=0}^{b}(-1)^{i}\frac{b!(b+1)!}{i!(b-i)!(i+1)}\\
 & = & b!\sum_{i=0}^{b}(-1)^{i}\frac{(b+1)!}{(i+1)!(b-i)!}\\
 & = & b!\sum_{i=0}^{b}(-1)^{i}\binom{b+\text{1}}{i+1}\\
 & = & b!\left(1-\sum_{i=0}^{b+1}(-1)^{i}\binom{b+\text{1}}{i}\right)\\
 & = & b!
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Can anyone see how to prove it for arbitrary $a$? Thanks!

Comment: The usual interpretation of "combinatoric proof" (that I'm accustomed to) is to show that the beta function counts *something*; what exactly do you mean by "combinatoric proof" here?

Comment: In any event: it might be more interesting to establish [this relationship](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/27/01/0006/) instead...

Comment: I'm with @J.M. - your derivation for $a=0$ doesn't really look like a combinatorial proof, as you're using only symbolic manipulation instead of counting and combining objects.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a combinatorial argument for $a!\,  b!  =  \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{(a+b+1)!}{(a+i+1)}$, which is just a slight rewrite of the identity you want to show.

Suppose you have $a$ red balls numbered $1$ through $a$, $b$ blue balls numbered $1$ through $b$, and one black ball.

*Question*: How many permutations of the balls have all the red balls first, then the black ball, and then the blue balls?

*Answer 1*: $a! \,b!$. There are $a!$ ways to choose the red balls to go in the first $a$ slots, $b!$ ways to choose the blue balls to go in the last $b$ slots, and $1$ way for the black ball to go in slot $a+1$.

*Answer 2*: Let $A$ be the set of all permutations in which the black ball appears after all the red balls (irrespective of where the blue balls go).  Let $B_i$ be the subset of $A$ such that the black ball appears after blue ball $i$.   Then the number of permutations we're after is also given by $|A| - \left|\bigcup_{i=1}^b B_i\right|$.  Since the probability that the black ball appears last of any particular $a+i+1$ balls is $\frac{1}{a+i+1}$, and there are $(a+b+1)!$ total ways to arrange the balls, by the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we get $$\frac{(a+b+1)!}{a+1} - \sum_{i=1}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i+1}\frac{(a+b+1)!}{(a+i+1)} =  \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{(a+b+1)!}{(a+i+1)}.$$

Comment: Fantastic! How did you find this?

Comment: @Steven: I thought about it for way too long. :)  More seriously, an alternating binomial sum smells like inclusion-exclusion to me.  I also thought I could generalize [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38623/how-to-prove-sum-limits-r-0n-frac-1rr1-binomnr-frac1n1/62753#62753) to a similar question, and that turned out to work, although it took a while to get the formulation right.  I kept trying to apply inclusion-exclusion to the full set of permutations, and it finally hit me that I only needed to consider subsets of the set I call $A$.  And thanks!

Comment: Nicely done indeed!

Comment: @robjohn: And thanks for the edit. Not sure how I managed to leave that out! :)

Comment: Beautiful, this is *exactly* the kind of answer I was hoping for, thank you!

Comment: Union from 1 to n should be from 1 to b btw - tried to edit but it didn't like the single-character change.

Comment: @Paul: You're right; I'll fix it.  Thanks for pointing it out.  (I think your attempted edit didn't work because you don't have enough rep yet to edit others' posts.)

Answer (score 8):

Using partial fractions, we have that
$$
\frac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)\dots(a+b+1)}=\frac{A_1}{a+1}+\frac{A_2}{a+2}+\dots+\frac{A_{b+1}}{a+b+1}\tag{1}
$$
Use the [Heaviside Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method); multiply $(1)$ by $(a+k)$ and set $a=-k$ to solve $(1)$ for $A_k$:
$$
A_k=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!(b-k+1)!}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{b!}\binom{b}{k-1}\tag{2}
$$
Plugging $(2)$ into $(1)$, yields
$$
\frac{a!}{(a+b+1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{b+1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{b!}\binom{b}{k-1}\frac{1}{a+k}\tag{3}
$$
Multiplying $(3)$ by $b!$ and reindexing, gives us
$$
\frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^{b}(-1)^k\binom{b}{k}\frac{1}{a+k+1}\tag{4}
$$
and $(4)$ is your identity.

---

**Update:** Starting from the basic binomial identity
$$
(1-x)^b=\sum_{k=0}^b(-1)^k\binom{b}{k}x^k\tag{5}
$$
multiply both sides of $(5)$ by $x^a$ and integrate from $0$ to $1$:
$$
B(a+1,b+1)=\sum_{k=0}^b(-1)^k\binom{b}{k}\frac{1}{a+k+1}\tag{6}
$$

Comment: FYI: This argument appears on pages 188-189 of *Concrete Mathematics*, 2nd edition, where it is discussed in the context of the $n$th forward difference formula.

Comment: This identity is one of my favorite uses of partial fractions and it turns up when using [Euler's Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform) for series acceleration.

Comment: @Mike: not surprising since it computes the $b^{th}$ forward difference of $\frac{1}{a+1}$.  Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 3):

Seven years later I found another way to attack this. Define $f(b, a) = \frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!}$ and $h(b, a) = \sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}$. To connect the two, we define $g$ such that $g(0, a) = \frac{1}{a + 1}$ and $g(b + 1, a) = g(b, a) - g(b, a + 1)$ and prove by induction in $b$ that $f = g = h$. In each case the base case is straightforward and we consider only the inductive step.

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & g(b + 1, a) \\
& = & g(b, a) - g(b, a + 1) \\
& = & f(b, a) - f(b, a + 1) \\
& = & \frac{a!b!}{(a+b+1)!} - \frac{(a+1)!b!}{(a+b+2)!} \\
& = & \frac{a!b!(a + b + 2)}{(a+b+2)!} - \frac{a!b!(a+1)}{(a+b+2)!} \\
& = & \frac{a!b!(b+1)}{(a+b+2)!} \\
& = & \frac{a!(b+1)!}{(a+b+2)!} \\
& = & f(b+1, a)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & g(b + 1, a) \\
& = & g(b, a) - g(b, a + 1) \\
& = & h(b, a) - h(b, a + 1) \\
& = & \left(\sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\right) - \left(\sum_{i=0}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+2}\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{a+1} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\right) - \left(\sum_{i=0}^{b-1}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+2}\right) - (-1)^{b}\frac{1}{a+b+2}\\
& = & \frac{1}{a+1} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{b}\binom{b}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\right) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{b}\binom{b}{i-1}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\right) + (-1)^{b+1}\frac{1}{a+b+2}\\
& = & \frac{1}{a+1} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{b}\left(\binom{b}{i} + \binom{b}{i-1}\right)(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\right) + (-1)^{b+1}\frac{1}{a+b+2}\\
& = & \frac{1}{a+1} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{b}\binom{b+1}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1}\right) + (-1)^{b+1}\frac{1}{a+b+2}\\
& = & \sum_{i=0}^{b+1}\binom{b+1}{i}(-1)^{i}\frac{1}{a+i+1} \\
& = & h(b + 1, a) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$