# Find general form for summation expression: $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am learning about combinatorics and am trying to solve the following problem.

Find the value of

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+1}$$

for several values of n.  What do you think is the value in general?  Prove it.

I have carried out some calculations for various values of n and I think that the solution in terms of $n$ is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

I also think that induction is not a very helpful way to prove this.

I would appreciate any **hints** (no complete solutions, please!).

Comment: Thanks, congratulations and $+1$ for asking only for hints and not for complete solutions.

Comment: Several proofs can be found here: [How to prove $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{r+1}\binom{n}{r} = \frac1{n+1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38623)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint(s):** write $\frac{1}{k+1}=\int_{0}^{1}x^k\,dx$, swap the sum and the integral, exploit the binomial theorem, compute the resulting integral through the substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$.

Comment: Using your hint, I get $\sum_{k=0}^n [{n \choose k}(-1)^k \int_0^1 x^k dx]$.  I'm not sure how to take the sum of an integral, though.

Comment: @CKKOY: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k x^k = (1-x)^n$. You just have to compute $\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^n\,dx.$

Comment: I've got the answer now!  The hints were useful.  :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try integrating the following summation

$$(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n (^n_k)(-1)^kx^k$$
$$\Rightarrow \int^1_0 (1-x)^n dx=\int^1_0 \sum_{k=0}^n (^n_k)(-1)^kx^kdx$$
Put the required value of x and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{n+1}{k+1}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Now Using $$(1+x)^{n+1} = \binom{n+1}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}x+\binom{n+1}{2}x^2+....+\binom{n+1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$$

Comment: How do you make the first step (from the LHS of the first equal sign to the RHS of that equal sign), please?

Comment: Using the formula $\displaystyle \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}$