# Prove $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I managed to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^k$$
on the left side, but I don't know how to proceed from here.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to prove $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{r+1}\binom{n}{r} = \frac1{n+1}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/38623) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5Ek%7D%7Bk%2B1%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand $(1-1)^{n+1}$ by using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement):
$$0=(1-1)^{n+1}=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k}=1-(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks alot! but I'm not sure how you get the "1-" before the sum? thanks again!

Comment: @Omer.S Because $(1-1)^{n+1}=\binom{n+1}{0}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}$.

Comment: I understand that $\ (1-1)^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose k+1} (-1)^{k+1}$ but why $\ {n+1\choose 0}$?

Comment: @Omer.S $$(1-1)^{n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j}(-1)^{j}=\binom{n+1}{0}+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{j}(-1)^{j}\\=\binom{n+1}{0}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{k+1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}&=&\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}z^n\,dz = \color{red}{\frac{1}{n+1}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$