# Evaluate the sum ${1 - \frac{1}{2} {n \choose 1} + \frac{1}{3} {n \choose 2} + \ldots + (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} {n \choose n}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Evaluate the sum $${1 - \frac{1}{2} {n \choose 1} + \frac{1}{3} {n \choose 2} + \ldots + (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} {n \choose n}}.$$

I have tried comparing this to the similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611761/alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-given-n-in-mathbb-n-prove-sumn).

I believe I need to differentiate or integrate? But I'm not sure how that might work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what does n mean

Comment: $n$ is a variable here. I don't need a numeric value, but rather a closed form (not a sum).

Comment: @grand_chat, thanks for the link. How did you find it?

Comment: @TylerDurden I used the search box with the terms *alternating binomial coefficient*. The link is on the second page of results.

Comment: See also [How to prove $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{r+1}\binom{n}{r} = \frac1{n+1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38623) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/38623).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}.$$ Then multiplying each term by $\frac{n+1}{n+1},$ we get $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k}.$$ Adding and subtracting $1$ and applying the Binomial Theorem gives $$\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}(-1)^{k}1^{n+1-k}=\frac{1}{n+1}(1-(1-1)^{n+1})=\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. When you say "Adding and subtracting $1$," could you clarify what that means?

Comment: Yep: We have a $k=0$ term missing in the previous line, and we observe that this is just $(-1)^{0-1}\binom{n+1}{0}=-1,$ so we add $1$ and subtract $1$ (in the form of the $k=0$ term), and of course, scale both by the multiplicative factor $1/(n+1)$ which is multiplying the rest of the sum.

Comment: Since we've really just added $0,$ the sum doesn't change, but having the $k=0$ term allows us to apply the Binomial Theorem. Also, love the user name, but let's not talk about that. And not talk about it.

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{n+1}(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} {n+1 \choose k}) = \frac{1}{n+1}(1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} {n+1 \choose k})$, where are you getting that negative sign in $\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} \ldots$ from?

Comment: Ah, you multiply the sum by $-1$ and add $1$ to the coefficient on $-1$ in the sum to make it $(-1)^k$. I see now.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
S&=1-\frac 12\binom n1+\frac 13 \binom n2-\cdots+(-1)^n\frac 1{n+1}\binom nn\\
\times (n+1):\hspace{1cm}\\
(n+1)S&=(n+1)-\frac {n+1}2\binom n1+\frac {n+1}3\binom n2-\cdots+(-1)^n\frac {n+1}{n+1}\binom nn\\
&=\binom {n+1}1-\binom {n+1}2+\binom {n+1}3-\cdots +(-1)^n\binom {n+1}{n+1}\\
&=\color{blue}{\binom {n+1}0}\underbrace{\color{blue}{-\binom {n+1}0}+\binom {n+1}1-\binom {n+1}2+\binom {n+1}3-\cdots +(-1)^n\binom {n+1}{n+1}}_{=-\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom {n+1}r(-1)^r=-(1-1)^{n+1}=0}\\
&=1\\
S&=\color{red}{\frac 1{n+1}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***

$${1 - \frac{1}{2} {n \choose 1} + \frac{1}{3} {n \choose 2} + \ldots + (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} {n \choose n}}.=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^j}{j+1} \binom n j $$

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^j}{j+1} x^{j+1} \binom n j =\int \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j x^{j}\binom n j =\int (1-x)^n=- \frac { (1-x)^{n+1}} {n+1} $$

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^j}{j+1} \binom n j =\int_0^1 (1-x)^n=\frac 1 {n+1}$$