# compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{(-1)^k}}{k+1}{n \choose k}$.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{(-1)^k}}{k+1}{n \choose k}$ as a function of n.

I have done it in the following way:

Notice first that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{(-1)^k}}{k+1}{n \choose k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}{n \choose k}$ Because for $k > n$ we have $n \choose k$ = 0.

Now, using the binomial theorem:

$$(1+x)^n =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}x^k $$

$$(1-x)^n =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k{n \choose k}x^k $$

$$\int(1-x)^ndx =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[(-1)^k{n \choose k}\int x^kdx] $$

$$ - \frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}{n \choose k}x^{k+1}$$

Now let x = 1 and we get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}{n \choose k} = - \frac{(1-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} = 0$$

However, the correct solution is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and not $0$.

I cant find my mistake, can someone help me find it please? Thank you!

**Edit**: I have seen different ways to prove my question, but I would still like to know where is my mistake so i would know how to avoid it in the next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \frac{(-1)^r}{r+1}\binom{n}{r} = \frac1{n+1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38623/how-to-prove-sum-limits-r-0n-frac-1rr1-binomnr-frac1n1)

Comment: @Aig Not really, there are nice answers in this link, but i still want to know where is my mistake, so i would know how to avoid it in the next time... Thank you though anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, when you integrated both sides, you forgot the constant of integration.

Instead of indefinite integration, you should apply the operator $\int_0^x$ to both sides. This does what you want on the right hand side, because
$$
\int_0^x \chi^k d\chi= \frac {x^{k+1}}{k+1}
$$
On the LHS, you will have $\int_0^x(1-\chi)^nd\chi$ which will provide the missing $1/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

I think you forgot the constant term when integrating…
$$\int(1-x)^ndx+C=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[(-1)^k{n \choose k}\int x^kdx] $$
Then let $x=0$ first, the correct number follows.